# SELECT - знаки вопроса вместо русских символов. JDBC, MySql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, кодировка

Вытягиваю данные из базы. Столкнулся с проблемой что русские символы получаются в виде знаков вопроса, хотя в самой таблице они нормально записаны.

Выполняю подключение к бд так:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:" + drivername + "://" + host + "/" + dbName + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8", User, Password);

stat = connection.createStatement();

stat.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
stat.execute("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Вытягиваю так:

```
String getdata = "Запрос";

PreparedStatement get = dbConnect.connection.prepareStatement(getdata);

result = get.executeQuery();

while(result.next()) {
    ...
}
```

Кодировки таблиц и самой БД - `utf-8`

Comment: Где конкретно они получаются в виде знаков вопроса? В консоли? В браузере? В файле? Скорее всего проблема не в запросе, а в устройстве вывода.

Comment: @rjhdby при извлечении в `servlet`-е уже получаются знаки вопроса.